# Angular 12 doesn't show error details in browser, only "Failed to compile."

Tags: angular

I am not sure if I am right, but did Angular used to show code errors with details in the browser, upon compiling the project.

Now on Angular 12 I only get darkened overlay screen with red:

> Failed to compile.

I can see errors in the terminal and some in the console, but think this might be useful. Am I doing something wrong or this is how it is in this version?

I am not asking about a specific error, but about the place where Angular displays error details (console, terminal and browser window).

Comment: You need to add the console errors to your question for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I am not asking about specific error. But about general error displaying in the browser's window view (not in developer tools) compared to in the terminal.